# Java 8 lambdas group list into map - different key if more than one list item per key

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of relationships. Each relationship object has three variables: personA, personB and relationshipType.

The relationshipType object has two variables: relationship (Son) and relationshipPlural (Sons)

I have a requirement where I need to list a person's relationships. If a person has one wife, it would be:

```
Wife      <wifeName>
```

If the person has more than one son, it would be:

```
    Sons      <firstSonName>
              <secondSonName>
```

Is there a simple lambda expression where I can turn a list of relationships into a `map<String,List<relationship>>` where if the key has a list with more than one item, then the key value is the relationshipType.relationshipPlural value?

The only option I can think of is using two expresions,

1) `Collectors.toMap()` to create a map of relationshipType, and then

2) process the map to create another map where the map's key will be relationshipType.relationshipPlural if map's value is a list with more than one value.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use `groupBy` for grouping them by type... but are you saying the key of the map would differ for single and multiple relations? (that might not be possible in a single pipeline neatly)

Comment: hello @Naman, thank you for your comment. Yes. If more than one relationship by relationshipType, then use relationshipType.relationshipPlural for map key. Else, use relationshipType.relationship. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `collectingAndThen` with `groupingBy` as downstream as :

```
private Map<String, List<RelationShip>> groupAndMapRelationships(List<RelationShip> relationShips) {
   return relationShips.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                   Collectors.groupingBy(RelationShip::getRelationshipType),
                   map -> map.entrySet().stream()
                           .map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(
                                   e.getValue().size() == 1 ?
                                           e.getKey().getRelationship() : e.getKey().getRelationshipPlural(),
                                   e.getValue()))
                           .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue))));
}
```

where the minimal POJOs I'd considered would look like :

```
@Getter
class RelationShip {
    String personA;
    String personB;
    RelationshipType relationshipType;
}

@Getter
class RelationshipType {
    String relationship;
    String relationshipPlural;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Naman. This is a really powerful solution. How did you go about figuring it out? How did you get your knowledge of streams? Is it through books/tutorials/trial and error? Thanks

Comment: @LucasT more from trial and error here from SO itself. :)